# How do I group the data into 5min user bins and subsequently count the records?

Tags: python, pandas, datatables

So I have a data frame containing timestamps:

```
new_date            id  
-------------------  ----  
2021-03-22 00:12:29 164616
2021-03-22 00:11:51 297284
2021-03-22 00:11:19 148817
2021-03-22 00:11:19 139208
2021-03-22 00:10:29 301459
2021-03-22 00:09:48 299543
2021-03-22 00:09:12 302444
```

I want to split the bins into 5 mins intervals and add together the number of ids of active users that fits withtin the bins.

```
new_date            id  
-------------------  ----  
2021-03-22 00:20:00 0
2021-03-22 00:15:00 13
2021-03-22 00:10:00 5
2021-03-22 00:05:00 2
```

so far I have tried

```
date["new_dates"] = pd.to_datetime(date['\tgp:last_session_date'], errors='coerce')
date = date.drop('\tgp:last_session_date', 1)
date.dropna()
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key ="new_dates", freq = '5Min')).agg({"\tuser_id": "count"})
```

But it gives a weird output with different dates.....

```
2021-02-24 18:45:00 1
2021-02-24 18:50:00 0
2021-02-24 18:55:00 0
2021-02-24 19:00:00 0
2021-02-24 19:05:00 0
```

Comment: try changing the `key` from `new_dates` to `timestamp`

Comment: could you please add a reproducible example? you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. but the idea is just to recreate your data frame in the code so people trying to answer can actually run your code.

Comment: Output is correct, but datetimes are not sorted, so in some another rows are dates with `2021-02-24`

Comment: @thethiny my bad, just fixed the colum names

Comment: @jezrael well this is the funny thing, there are no records in the table dating to 02-24. Although there were a few outliers from 03.21, but nothing from February that's for sure!

Comment: Try to filter the output where `count > 1`?

Answer (score 0):

I think ouput is expected, if there is some `'lost'` datetime near `2021-02-24 18:45:00`.

You can sorting original data for see it:

```
df = df.sort_values('new_date')
```

So then this row is count for `1` and next values are `0`, because not exist this datetimes in data (and ouput is consecutive DatetimeIndex)

EDIT:

If need remove NaNs is necessary return back ouput for [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), else not working (or use alternative):

```
date["new_dates"] = pd.to_datetime(date['\tgp:last_session_date'], errors='coerce')
date = date.drop('\tgp:last_session_date', 1)
date = date.dropna()
#alternative
#date.dropna(inplace=True)

df = df.sort_values('new_date')
print (df)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key ="new_dates", freq = '5Min')).agg({"\tuser_id": "count"})
```

Comment: I looked through it and it seems like there was indeed a cell with "02-24",  furthermore there seem to be a bunch of NaT values ..

Why woul there be NaT values If I have previously removed them with df.dropna()